# Finding Fourier series coefficients for discrete time signal

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-series, periodic

> Let $x[n]$ be a periodic sequence with period $N$ and Fourier series representation $$x[n] = \sum _{k=<N>}a_ke^{jk\frac{2\pi}{N}n}$$ Determine the Fourier series coefficients for
> $$y[n]  =
> \begin{cases}
> x[n],  & \text{if $n$ is even} \\[2ex]
> 0, & \text{if $n$ is odd}
> \end{cases}$$

## My try

### $N$ even

We have $x[0], 0 , x[2] , 0 , \dots x[N-2] , 0 , x[N]$.

Since $x[0] = x[N]$ the sequence $y[n]$ is periodic with $N$. Also we have

$$e^{jM\frac{2\pi}{N}n}x[n] \leftrightarrow a_{k-M}$$Let $M = \frac{N}{2}$, then $(-1)^nx[n] \leftrightarrow a_{k-\frac{N}{2}}$.
In this case $$b_k = \frac{1}{2}(a_k + a_{k-\frac{N}{2}})$$

### $N$ odd

By writing the first terms of $y[n]$, we see that $y[n]$ is periodic with period $2N$

$$x[0], 0 , x[2] , 0 , \dots x[N-1] , 0 , x[N+1] , 0 , x[N+3] , \dots , 0 , x[2N]$$Which is $$x[0], 0 , x[2] , 0 , \dots x[N-1] , 0 , x[1] , 0 , x[3] , \dots , 0 , x[0]$$

So we write

\begin{align}
b_k &= \frac{1}{2N}\sum _{n=<2N>}y[n]e^{\frac{-jk\pi n}{N}}\\
 &= \frac{1}{2N}     \sum _{n=0}^{\frac{N-1}{2}}x[2n]
                e^{\frac{-jk2\pi n}{N}} +
    \frac{(-1)^k}{2N}\sum _{n=1}^{\frac{N-1}{2}}x[2n-1]
                e^{\frac{-jk\pi (2n-1)}{N}}.
\end{align}

I don't know how to proceed further and how to relates $b_k$ and $a_k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For odd $N$ you can write the DFS coefficients $b_k$ of $y[n]$ as

$$\begin{align}b_k&=\frac{1}{2N}\sum_{n=0}^{2N-1}x[n]\frac{1+e^{-jn\pi}}{2}e^{-j\frac{2\pi nk}{2N}}\\&=\frac{1}{4N}\sum_{n=0}^{2N-1}x[n]e^{-j\frac{2\pi nk}{2N}}+\frac{1}{4N}\sum_{n=0}^{2N-1}x[n]e^{-j\frac{2\pi n(k+N)}{2N}}\tag{1}\end{align}$$

By splitting each sum in Eq. $(1)$ into two sums with indices ranging from $n=0$ to $n=N-1$ it can be shown that the first sum is zero for odd $k$, and the second sum is zero for $k+N$ odd, i.e., for even $k$. Consequently, for even $k$ only the first sum remains, and it equals $\frac12 a_{k/2}$, and for odd $k$ only the second sum remains, which equals $\frac12a_{(k+N)/2}$.

In sum, the result is

$$b_k=\begin{cases}\frac12 a_{k/2},&k\textrm{ even}\\\frac12 a_{(k+N)/2},&k\textrm{ odd}\end{cases}\tag{2}$$

---

Just a simple example in order to illustrate the relation between $a_k$ and $b_k$ as expressed in Eq. $(2)$:

We choose

`N = 5;`

and

`x = [1,2,3,4,5];`

As correctly explained in the OP, the sequence $y[n]$ has a length of $2N=10$:

`y = [1,0,3,0,5,0,2,0,4,0];`

The DFS coefficients are just the DFT coefficients scaled by the inverse of the period. So we have

```
A = fft(x) / N;
B = fft(y) / (2*N);
```

According to $(2)$, apart from a scaling, the coefficients $b_k$ are obtained by filling the even indices starting from $a_0$, and filling the odd indices starting from $a_{(N+1)/2}=a_3$. So we should get

`B2 = .5 * [A(1),A(4),A(2),A(5),A(3),A(1),A(4),A(2),A(5),A(3)];`

which gives

```
B-B2
ans =

  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Obviously, the coefficients $b_k$ are $N$-periodic, even though $y[n]$ has period $2N$. This is a well-known property of sequences for which all odd elements vanish.

Comment: $a_k$ that you used in your answer, and the $a_k$ that OP used in his answer (to the even part) might be confusing. The former is the DFS of the $2N$ length sequence, while the latter is the DFS of the length $N$ sequence, that he is interested in to express N-point Fourier series coefficients $b_k$ in terms of.

Comment: as he says *don't know how to proceed further and how to relates bk and ak*. in the last line.

Comment: @Fat32: $a_k$ are just the DFS coefficients of $x[n]$, and $b_k$ are the DFS coefficients of $y[n]$, just like in the question.

Comment: Let me go solid. Assume N = 3, and let x = [1,4,4] , then y = [1,0,4].  Then compute ak of x[n] as: ak = [9,-3-3] (real sequence), then compute bk of y[n] as : [5 ,  -1+ 3.4641*j ,  -1- 3.4641*j ] (a complex sequence)... Now how do you get the complex sequence bk from the real sequence ak as in your Eq.2 if ak is the 3-point DFS of x[n]? That's what I think is a risk of confusion. Looking at the top (quoted) part of the question, it's understood that ak is the N-point DFS of x[n].

Comment: @Fat32 Note that in the case $N=3$, the sequence $y[n]$ is periodic with $N = 2\times 3 = 6$.

Comment: @S.H.W ,yes and that's why there's the source of confusion. Then recasting my example let N=3, and x = [1,4,4], then y = [1,0,4,0,4,0]. Now 3-point DFS of x[n] is ak = [9,-3-3], and 6-point DFS of y[n] is bk = [9,-3,-3,9,-3,-3]. Now, it's not only inconsistent with Eq.2 above, but also it can be seen that ak = bk. So I think you should interpret y[n] to be periodic with 3 and use the definition y[n]=x[n],n:even, y[n]=0,n:odd only for the range 0<= n < N-1. Then you will have 3 point periodic sequences.

Comment: @S.H.W If you interpret y[n] as periodic by 2xN, (which is the case if you consider x[n] as an indefinetely extending periodic sequence) then Eq.2 is correct except for the scale factor of 0.5 which should be one. And also my counter-example x=[1,4,4] was a magic sequence (real & even symmetric) of length 3 for which ak = bk holds true :-) However, you can as well treat y[n] to be periodic by N , by only sampling x[n] in its base period. My answers are based on that interpretation. The question should have made it clear though. as both interpretations can have their applications.

Comment: @Fat32 I see. Anyway, your answers are really fascinating. Thank you so much.

Comment: If we stick to the definitions of the OP ($y[n]$ has length/period $2N$), then also the scaling in Eq. (2) is correct, as illustrated by an example.

Comment: I see (lately) that OP's quoted question uses an **odd** way of expressing $x[n]$ in the **inverse** DFS relation (omtting the scale of 1/N ?)... Then  your scaling makes sense of course... I have dervied my equations based on the standard convention, where the scale is omitted in the forward transform and used in the backward (just a matter of convention). And I can hardly make sense of using the opposite of the standard version though.

Comment: @Fat32: That definition of the DFS (not DFT) is actually quite common. It is the one used for instance in Oppenheim's "Signals and Systems".

Comment: I saw it now ! shocking ! Yes he uses the opposite convention to that he uses in DTSP book. So in the future we have to answer questions based on which book they are asked from... :-). It's my bad, I didn't even read the question carefully...

Comment: @MattL. I think you mean $$\sum_{n=0}^{2N-1}x[n]e^{-j\frac{2\pi nk}{2N}} = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x[n]e^{-j\frac{2\pi nk}{2N}} + \sum_{n=N}^{2N-1}x[n]e^{-j\frac{2\pi nk}{2N}} = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x[n]e^{-j\frac{2\pi nk}{2N}} + \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x[n]e^{-j\frac{2\pi nk}{2N}}(-1)^k$$ which is zero for odd $k$. Is that correct?

Comment: @S.H.W: That's right, and similarly for the other sum.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for DFS (discrete Fourier series) coefficients $b_k$ of the periodic sequence $y[n]$, in terms $a_k$ of the periodic sequence $x[n]$. Since DFS and DFT (discrete Fourier transform) are the same things, I will instead write down an answer for the DFTs $Y[k]$ and $X[k]$ of the associated sequences, in the context of which $X[k] = a_k$ , and $Y[k] = b_k$ will be understood.

I would like to relate DFTs to DTFTs (discrete-time Fourier transform) through the sampling relation, which indicates that :

> N-point DFT X[k] of the N-point sequence x[n], is the uniform samples of the DTFT X(w) of
> x[n].

The DTFT of $x[n]$ is :

$$ X(\omega) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n] e^{-j \omega n } \tag{a}$$

and the DFT of $x[n]$ is :

$$ X[k] = X(\frac{2\pi}{N}k) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n] e^{-j \frac{2\pi}{N}nk } \tag{b}$$
Let $x[n]$ and $y[n]$ be two sequences related by:
$$y[n]=\begin{cases}{ x[n] ~~~,~~~n:even \\  ~~~0 ~~~~~,~~~ n:odd }\end{cases}$$

You can also express $y[n]$ as :

$$ x[n] \longrightarrow \boxed{ \downarrow 2 } \overset{w[n]}{\longrightarrow} \boxed{ \uparrow 2 }    \longrightarrow y[n] $$

Applying DTFT relations to the sequences :

$$ W(\omega) = 0.5 \left( X\left( \frac{\omega}{2} \right) +  X\left( \frac{\omega-2\pi}{2} \right) \right) \tag{1} $$

and

$$ Y(\omega) = W(2\omega) \tag{2} $$

hence

$$ Y(\omega) = 0.5 \left( X\left( \omega \right) +  X\left( \omega-\pi\right) \right) \tag{3} $$

Eq.3 describes the relation (for any $N$) between the DTFTs $Y(\omega)$ and $X(\omega)$ of the sequences $x[n]$, and $y[n]$. To turn this into the equivalent relation between the N-point DFTs $X[k]$ and $Y[k]$, (and for your case a relation between DFS  $a_k$ and $b_k$) we shall sample the associated DTFTs. Then we have :

$$  \begin{align}
Y[k] &= Y( \frac{2\pi}{N} k ) ~~~,~~~k = 0,1,...,N-1 \tag{4} \\ \\
     &= 0.5 \left( X\left( \frac{2\pi}{N} k \right) +  X\left( \frac{2\pi}{N} k-\pi\right) \right) \tag{5} \\ \\
     &\boxed{ Y[k] = 0.5 \left( X\left[ k \right] +  X\left[k- \frac{N}{2} \right] \right) }\tag{6} \\
\end{align}$$

Eq.6 describes the requested relation between N-point DFTs $X[k]$ and $Y[k]$.

When $N$ is **EVEN** (say $N = 2 M$ ) the relation becomes :

$$ \boxed{ Y[k] = 0.5 ( X[k] + X[k-M] ) }\tag{7} $$

which is what you have arrived at $b_k = 0.5(a_k + a_{k -\frac{N}{2}})$.

However, when $N$ is **ODD**, there is a problem due to $N/2$ not being an integer. The sequence $X[k-N/2]$ is interpreted as an **interpolation** of $X[k]$ at the fractional indices $k-N/2$.

For $N=2M+1$ , we have $X[k-N/2] = X[k-M-0.5]$ , $k=0,1,...,N-1$ , which evaluates $X[k]$ at the points $m = 0.5,1.5,...,N-0.5$. To get those intermediate samples, we need an interpolation of $X[k]$ by 2.

Interpolation of $X[k]$ by 2, is achieved by **zero padding** $x[n]$ by $N$ samples, and computing its $2N$-point DFT :

$$ x_e[n] = \begin{cases}{ x[n] ~~~,~~~ 0 \leq n < N \\ ~~~0 ~~~~ , ~~~~ N \leq n < 2N }\end{cases} $$

Then we can see, by the DFT - DTFT sampling relation that :

$$ \mathcal{DFT}\{x_e[n]\} =X_2[k] = X(\frac{2\pi}{2N}k )= X(\frac{2\pi}{N} k/2 ) = X[k/2] \tag{8} $$

for $ k = 0,1,.,2N-1$. Note that DTFTs of $x[n]$ and $x_e[n]$ are the same.

Based on Eqs. 8, you can restate Eq.6 when $N$ is odd :

$$ \boxed{ Y[k]= 0.5 \big( X\left[ k \right] +  X_2\left[2k- N\right] \big) } \tag{9} $$

with your notation it becomes:
$$ b_k = 0.5 ( a_k + a^e_{2k-N} ) $$ where $a^e$ is the DFS of the sequence $x_e[n]$.

As you can see, you cannot express $b_k$ (with a simple formula) in terms of sole $a_k$ when $N$ is odd.

Answer (score 1):

A more simpler interpretation of the required $b_k$ is based on the DTFT relation between $x[n]$ and $y[n]$, as stated in my first answer :

$$Y(\omega) = 0.5 \left( X(\omega) + X(\omega - \pi) \right) \tag{1} $$

It's simple to show that $X(\omega-\pi)$ is the DTFT of the sequence $(-1)^n x[n]$.
We can denote that new sequence as $x_s[n]$, and its DTFT as $X_s(\omega) = X(\omega-\pi)$. Then Eq.1 becomes :

$$Y(\omega) = 0.5 \left( X(\omega) + X_s(\omega ) \right) \tag{2} $$

And we can simply apply $N$-point DFT samlping on Eq.2 to get DFT $Y[k]$ :

$$Y[k] = Y(\frac{2\pi}{N}k) = 0.5 \left( X(\frac{2\pi}{N}k) + X_s(\frac{2\pi}{N}k) \right) = 0.5 \left( X[k]+X_s[k]\right) \tag{3} $$

Hence for all $N$ even or odd,
$$Y[k] = X[k] + X_s[k] ~~~,~~~k=0,1,...,N-1 \tag{4}$$

where $X_s[k]$ is the $N$-point DFT of the sequence $x_s[n] = (-1)^n x[n]$ , $n=0,1,..,N-1$.

In terms of DFS sequences Eq.4 becomes:

$$b_k = a_k + {a^s}_k ~~~,~~~ k=0,1,...,N-1 \tag{5}$$

where ${a^s}_k$ is the $N$-point DFT of the sequence $x_s[n] = (-1)^n x[n]$ , $n=0,1,..,N-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another interpretation of the requested DFS coefficients can be obtained by one of the DFS (or DFT) properties known as **modulation** theorem which states that

If the N-point sequences  $x[n]$ and $w[n]$ has $N$-point DFS sequences $a_k$ and $w_k$, then we have :

$$ x[n] \cdot w[n] \overset{DFS} \longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{N} ~ a_k ~ \overset{N} {\star} ~w_k \tag{1}$$

Where the right side of Eq.1 is the N-point circular convolution of the sequences $a_k$ and $b_k$ (for DFS sequences it's interpreted as N-point periodic convolution).

Then one can see that $y[n]$ is related to $x[n]$ by :

$$y[n] = x[n]\cdot w[n] \tag{2} $$

where $w[n] = 0.5(1 + (-1)^n) $. Then applying the modulation theorem in Eq.1, and nothing that

$$ w_k = 0.5 \cdot \left( N \delta[k] + \frac{1 -(-1)^N}{1 + e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{N}k}} \right) \\\\$$

$$ w_k = \begin{cases}{ \frac{N}{2} ( \delta[k] + \delta[k-N/2] ~~~,~~~ N:even \tag{3}\\  \frac{N}{2} \delta[k] + \frac{1}{1 + e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{N}k}} ~~~~~~~~~~~,~~~ N:odd }\end{cases} \\\\$$

Then we can see that the N-point DFS coefficients $b_k$ of $y[n]$ is given by:

$$b_k = \frac{1}{N} ( a_k \star w_k) \\ \tag{4}$$

$$ b_k = \begin{cases}{ 0.5 a_k + 0.5 a_{k-N/2} ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~,~~ N:even \tag{5} \\ \\   0.5 a_k + \frac{1}{N} \sum_{m=0}^{N-1} a_{k-m} \frac{1}{1 + e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{N}m}} ~~~~~~~~~~~,~~~ N:odd }\end{cases} \\\\$$

$k = 0,1,...,N-1$.

Answer (score 1):

As if three mis-interpretations were not sufficient, I'm putting yet another interpretation of the problem, this time from the perspective of OP (which is also taken by MattL in his answer) who considers $y[n]$ to be a $2N$-point periodic sequence, where my previous three answers assumed $y[n]$ as of length $N$, anyway.

The definition

$$ y[n] = \begin{cases} { x[n] ~~~,~~~ n:even \\ ~~~ 0 ~~~ ~~, ~~~ n:odd }\end{cases} $$

for $n=0,1,...,2N-1$ can be represented by the following block diagram :

$$ x[n] \longrightarrow \boxed{1:2} \overset{w[n]} \longrightarrow \boxed{\downarrow 2} \overset{v[n]} \longrightarrow \boxed{\uparrow 2} \longrightarrow y[n]$$

where $x[n]$ is of length $N$, $w[n]$ of length $2N$, $v[n]$ of $N$, and $y[n]$ is of length $2N$. Note that the first block is a **repeater** (concatenator) (by 2 in this case).

Now, the freq-domain equivalent of the above time-domain block for all $N$ is:
$$ 2X[k] \longrightarrow \boxed{\uparrow 2} \overset{W[k]} \longrightarrow \boxed{\%N}  \underset{0.5} {\overset{V[k]} \longrightarrow}  \boxed{1:2} \longrightarrow Y[k]$$

Where the middle block is an **aliaser**, which aliases $W[k]$ of length $2N$ into $V[k]$ of length $N$ sequence (and also divides by 2). All DFT sequences have their lengths equal to their time domain counterparts.

Hence, the **dual** block diagram expresses the $2N$-point DFT $Y[k]$ of the $2N$-point sequence $y[n]$, in terms of $N$-point DFT $X[k]$ of $N$-point sequence $x[n]$.

Now we have the following relations :

$ Y[k] = V[(k)_N] ~~~,~~ k=0,1,...,2N-1 \\\\$

$V[k] = 0.5( W[k] + W[k+N] ) ~~~,~~~ k=0,1,...,N-1 \\\\$

$ W[k] = \begin{cases} {2 X[k/2] ~~~, ~~~ k = 0,2,4,...2N-1 \\ ~~~~~~ 0 ~~~~~~~~ , ~~~~ k=1,3,...,2N-1 \\} \end{cases} $

From which you can deduce that :

For $N$ **EVEN:**

$Y[k] =\begin{cases} { X[\frac{(k)_N}{2}] + X[ \frac{(k)_N+N}{2}] ~~~ , ~~~ k=0,2,4,...,2N-1 \\ ~~~0 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ , k= 1,3,5,...,2N-1 \\ }\end{cases}$

And for $N$ **ODD:**

$Y[k] =\begin{cases} { X[\frac{(k)_N}{2}]  ~~~~ , ~~~~~~ k=0,2,4,...,2N-1 \\ X[ \frac{(k)_N+N}{2}] ~~~~, k= 1,3,5,...,2N-1 }\end{cases}$

which is identical to Eq.2 of MattL for odd N, (except the scale factor). **NOTE** the *modulus* operator on the indices of the sequence $X[k]$.